# Is it OK to find out what the method returns calling the method itself inside it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know the question sounds confusing, but it should sound simpler if I just show it with code:

Is it OK to do the following:

```
- (void)foo {
     if (bar()) { // do something }
}
BOOL bar() {
     return [self foo];
}
```

Comment: Note that you’ve defined `-foo` as returning `void` so it doesn’t make sense to return `[self foo]`. Also, note that you’ve defined `bar()` as a function instead of a method.

Answer (score 1):

This will be called recursively until `[self foo]` returns NO.

Technically its 'ok' just make sure you know what you're doing.